# Silverlight import references

Tags: silverlight

If I have a silverlight project and silverlight class library.

In the class library I imported the silverlighttoolkit.dll. The silerlight project imports this class library and also the silverlighttoolkit.dll. Will that make my xap file larger? How do I handle something like this? Should I use the toolkit dll through the class library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the XAP will only pull in the library once.